# How to invite Facebook, twitter, gmail, Yahoo friends in drupal 7 to join drupal site

Tags: drupal-7

I have to invite Facebook, twitter, gmail, Yahoo friends in drupal 7 to join drupal 7 site. I have searched drupal module for that but did not found any module. Is there any module to perform this above task. Or any other way that i can perform to complete this task anyone know please let me know.

Thank you,
Rahul Barge